# Is docker compatible with freebsd 10?

Tags: docker, freebsd

I'm trying to install docker into a server that has freebsd OS, the version of freebsd is **10.3-RELEASE-p17**. I want to know if docker is compatible with this version of freebsd and also how can I install it? 
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Search more about jails (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail) you may not need docker

Comment: Take a look at the [code frequency](https://github.com/kvasdopil/docker/graphs/code-frequency). There hasn't been any activity in the project since 2015.

Comment: See [FreeBSD Jails or Docker instances](https://serverfault.com/questions/944354/freebsd-jails-or-docker-instances).

Comment: I really need docker, I'm deploying something in docker and I have Jenkins installed on a FreeBSD server and I want to automate the deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker won't work of FreeBSD(at least as of now). Docker was built built for Linux- it uses the isolation features of the linux kernel. There have been ongoing efforts to have a working port but there's nothing concrete(for the past 9 months). If you'd want to run docker, you'd have to use a VM and run docker from that VM using docker-machine(which is ports). I've mentioned `virtualbox` because it's supported by docker-machine.